# Get images form DOM/PHP to use in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm using the following code as part of jQuery slider/grid animation (full code found [here](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/grid-animation-effects). I am trying to have it pull images dynamically echoed from Wordpress instead of based on a naming structure.

```
var images = "", count = ;
for(var i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    images += '<img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/u/uifaces/'+i+'.jpg" />';
```

My markup looks like this:

```
<ul class="about-us-grid">
<?php $posts = get_posts('post_type=employee&orderby=rand&numberposts=24'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
<li>
<img  class="headshot" src="<?php the_field('headshot'); ?>">
</li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

I've tried variations on this

```
var images = "", count = 24;
for(var i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    images += '.headshot';
```

But no luck. How do I changes to pick images based on the class not the url/counter?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the code shown? `pull images` isn't a clear objective

Comment: `$('img.headshot').each(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution, just had to replace Var with this:

```
var images = jQuery('img.headshot')
```